# WordPress test environment keeps redirecting to live

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

WordPress is new for me. I want to fix a bug in a WordPress site for a client. Tries to setup a test environment using Scotch Box, but the website keeps redirecting to the live environment.
I have tried the following

1. Changed 'siteurl' and 'home' in the db to the new URl.
2. Tried the same with DEFINE in wp-config:

   ```
   define('WP_HOME','http://192.168.33.10');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://192.168.33.10');
   ```
3. I even put a `die();` in the `index.php` file, which it apparently doesn't even reach as it is still redirecting.
4. Searched all the code in the website to look for a hardcoded redirect somewhere. There was none.
5. Looked for a `.htaccess` file, there is none.
6. Looked at a lot of Stack Overflow questions that all suggested the above methods.

I do not really understand how this is possible. Is there anything else I should try? Btw, the website is using the 'Maxima Theme'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, chrome was redirecting the ip.. Worked with another browser and now works with Chrome after clearing the browser data.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue in Firefox, solved it by using the developer tools to disable the cache:

1. Open Web Developer Tools - Either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, or use the menu.
2. Choose the **Network** tab.
3. Tick the **Disable Cache** box.

Credit: https://superuser.com/a/661767/178934